# Building emacs 25.2 fails with "gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory"

Tags: emacs, building

On Oracle Linux 6.9 (similar to Centos) I try to build GNU Emacs 25.2. `make` fails on

```
CCLD     temacs
```

with

```
gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
```

Same problem occurs when building Emacs 25.3.

The strange things is: I did build Emacs 25.2 six months ago on the same machine and it built fine, but now the exact same tarball gives the above mentioned error.

Any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: What package contains libgomp.spec and have you tried to install the missing package?  Alternatively, how about finding out what feature Emacs uses that requires that package and see if there is an exclusion for the command line build options.

Comment: @lawlist How do I find out which package contains `libgomp.spec`?

Comment: @lawlist A brief Google search for `libgomp.spec` gives hits which point towards some OpenMP or MS Windows issue. - I'm on Linux. Strange!

Comment: Threads dealing with MinGW on Windows are similar to Linux in that MinGW lets Windows users compile stuff like on LInux.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for your pointers! Have solved the issue now; see answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@lawlist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2112489/lawlist)'s probing in the comments I got on the right track to pinpoint the problem:

During the last couple of months V6 of gcc was installed  and this version doesn't seem to have the needed packages containing `libgomp.spec`.

My solution was to switch back to V4 of gcc and everything went smoothly through.