# Install rJava package on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rjava, sendmailr

I am using R on AWS EC2 instance.
I am trying to send a mail using the "mailR" package.

I was told that to install the package I should previously install the package "rJava" as "mailR" depends on it.

When trying to install "rJava" I get this error:

> gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory

After a quick search, I saw a post on this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/194047/) explaining this:

> "You have to make sure your GCC has OpenMP support enabled.
>   Make sure you select OpenMP from the optional packages when installing."

I really have no idea how to do this.
Should it be something to add in the parameters of install.packages("rJava")?

Assistance much appreciated !

M.

Comment: It's complaining about a missing system file, not a missing R package. You need to fix or enhance your GCC and OpenMP installation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858821/building-emacs-25-2-fails-with-gcc-error-libgomp-spec-no-such-file-or-direct)

I did install gcc but apparently we should not install the latest version, so as suggested in the linked post, I downloaded version 4 and it worked.

You do that by typing in Putty:

```
sudo yum install gcc-4.8.5
```

Thanks !